# How do I obtain the value of another observable, without it affecting the parent stream's return value

Tags: rxjs

I want to make an http request, without affecting the value of the parent stream:

```
const mockHttpCall = () => of('http-result');

of('result1')
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() =>
      mockHttpCall().pipe(  
        tap((innerResult) => console.log('innerResult: ', innerResult))
      )
    )
  )
```

ie: this stream should return `result1` rather than `http-result`.

How can I do this? I think something might be possible using `withLatestFrom` and `map` back to the original value but not sure if it is good idea.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-lrcuse?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just `map` back to the original value:

```
of('result1')
  .pipe(
    switchMap((result) =>
      mockHttpCall().pipe(  
        tap((innerResult) => console.log('innerResult: ', innerResult)),
        map(() => result)
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: You can also use `mapTo()` to remove the need for an inner function. `mapTo(result)`